# guide to move from filter to withFilter?

Tags: scala

Is there a detailed guide to move from filter() to withFilter()? Now I get warnings about my using filter() implementations but can't find an easy guide for moving to withFilter()...

Answer (score 21):

You can relive the birth of `withFilter` on [the mailing list](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Rethinking-filter-td2009215.html#a2009218).

And check out [the diff](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/source/diff?spec=svn506&r=506&format=side&path=/trunk/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala) that brought it to Scalacheck.

Comment: ScalaCheck has moved. That link is now invalid.