# Scala for comprehension efficiency?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

In the book "Programming In Scala", chapter 23, the author give an example like:

```
case class Book(title: String, authors: String*)
val books: List[Book] = // list of books, omitted here
// ﬁnd all authors who have published at least two books

for (b1 <- books; b2 <- books if b1 != b2;
    a1 <- b1.authors; a2 <- b2.authors if a1 == a2)
yield a1
```

The author said, this will translated into:

```
books flatMap (b1 =>
   books filter (b2 => b1 != b2) flatMap (b2 =>
      b1.authors flatMap (a1 =>
        b2.authors filter (a2 => a1 == a2) map (a2 =>
           a1))))
```

But if you look into the map and flatmap method definition(*TraversableLike.scala*), you may find, they are defined as for loops:

```
   def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    b.sizeHint(this) 
    for (x <- this) b += f(x)
    b.result
  }

  def flatMap[B, That](f: A => Traversable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    for (x <- this) b ++= f(x)
    b.result
  }
```

Well, I guess this for will continually be translated to foreach and then translated to while statement which is a construct not an expression, scala doesn't have a for construct, because it wants the for always yield something.

So, what I want to discuss with you is that, why does Scala do this "For translation" ?
The author's example used 4 generators, which will be translated into 4 level nested for loop in the end, I think it'll have really horrible performance when the `books` is large.

Scala encourage people to use this kind of "Syntactic Sugar", you can always see codes that heavily make use of filter, map and flatmap, which seems programmers are forgetting what they really do is nesting one loop inside another, and what achieved is only to make codes looks a bit shorter. What's your idea?

Comment: Where does the map/flatMap/filter definitions you mention come from?

Comment: @Daniel Well, these definitions are from Chapter 23.5 of "Programming In Scala" - Martin Ordersky. Yeah, it's bad to illustrate this problem, I have changed it to TraversableLike.scala definitions.

Comment: Ref 10.4 and 10.5 in http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf for those ho has not got  "Programming In Scala"

Comment: Note that they are defined as `foreach` loops. That's only to be expected, since that's the only method someone needs to implement on `Traversable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For comprehensions are syntactic sugar for monadic transformation, and, as such, are useful in all sorts of places. At that, they are much more verbose in Scala than the equivalent Haskell construct (of course, Haskell is non-strict by default, so one can't talk about performance of the construct like in Scala).

Also important, this construct keeps what is being done clear, and avoids quickly escalating indentation or unnecessary private method nesting.

As to the final consideration, whether that hides the complexity or not, I'll posit this:

```
for {
  b1 <- books
  b2 <- books
  if b1 != b2
  a1 <- b1.authors
  a2 <- b2.authors 
  if a1 == a2
} yield a1
```

It is very easy to see what is being done, and the complexity is clear: b^2 * a^2 (the filter won't alter the complexity), for number of books and number of authors. Now, write the same code in Java, either with deep indentation or with private methods, and try to ascertain, in a quick look, what the complexity of the code is.

So, imho, this doesn't hide the complexity, but, on the contrary, makes it clear.

As for the `map`/`flatMap`/`filter` definitions you mention, they do not belong to `List` or any other class, so they won't be applied. Basically,

```
for(x <- List(1, 2, 3)) yield x * 2
```

is translated into

```
List(1, 2, 3) map (x => x * 2)
```

and that is not the same thing as

```
map(List(1, 2, 3), ((x: Int) => x * 2)))
```

which is how the definition you passed would be called. For the record, the actual implementation of `map` on `List` is:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(repr)
  b.sizeHint(this) 
  for (x <- this) b += f(x)
  b.result
}
```

Comment: IMHO, Why people never doubt it's probably the problem of Scala? I remember there's a library in java called Lambda4j, which can make java incorporate closure feature and write DSL style codes. It heavily make use of introspections and dynamic proxies, you could write very high level code with it but should pay a performance trade-off. Well, after exploring Scala with a few months, I found Scala is just like Lambda4j, makes me feel like I'm not using a language, but a library, the high-level characteristics are over encapsulated with basic constructs, not the advantage of language design.

Comment: @ZZCat Introspection and dynamic proxies have a high cost in JVM, but neither are used by Scala by and large.

Comment: with my current comprehension, Scala just simulates some of the functional programming languages(Hashell) features, all the translations are just like methods calls. you can defines a methods named "for" and delegate the tasks to a while statement in the body, but it doesn't do this because it want "for" to be more natural.

Comment: Haskell's monad comprehensions also get translated to method calls. Just sayin'

Comment: @ZZCat It doesn't "simulate" anything. It translates the language into something else, just like every other compiled language does. Otherwise, we could say every object oriented language "simulates" OO, because it translates that into machine code.

Answer (score 6):

I write code so that it's easy to understand and maintain.  I then profile.  If there's a bottleneck that's where I devote my attention.  If it's in something like you've described I'll attack the problem in a different manner.  Until then, I love the "sugar."  It saves me the trouble of writing things out or thinking hard about it.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually 6 loops. One loop for each filter/flatMap/map

The filter->map pairs can be done in one loop by using lazy views of the collections (iterator method)

In general, tt is running 2 nested loops for books to find all book pairs and then two nested loops to find if the author of one book is in the list of authors of the other.

Using simple data structures, you would do the same when coding explicitly.

And of course, the example here is to show a complex 'for' loop, not to write the most efficient code. E.g., instead of a sequence of authors, one could use a Set and then find if the intersection is non empty:

```
for (b1 <- books; b2 <- books; a <- (b1.authors & b2.authors)) yield a
```

Comment: You forgot the if b1 != b2 condition.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in 2.8, the `filter` call was changed to `withFilter` which is lazy and would avoid constructing an intermediate structure. See [guide to move from filter to withFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188316/guide-to-move-from-filter-to-withfilter/4188866#4188866).

I believe the reason that `for` is translated to `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` (as well as value definitions if present) is to make the use of monads easier.

In general I think if the computation you are doing involves looping 4 times, it is fine using the `for` loop. If the computation can be done more efficiently and performance is important then you should use the more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One follow-up to @IttayD's answer on the algorithm's efficiency. It's worth noting that the algorithm in the original post (and in the book) is a **nested loop join**. In practice, this isn't an efficient algorithm for large datasets, and most databases would use a **hash aggregate** here instead. In Scala, a hash aggregate would look something like:

```
(for (book <- books;
      author <- book.authors) yield (book, author)
).groupBy(_._2).filter(_._2.size > 1).keys
```