# Scala For-Loop / For-Yield Optimization?

Tags: scala, lambda, for-comprehension

In Scala, `for` and `for-yield` loops are usually translated to a squence of `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` calls with Lambdas. Since the compiler converts there Lambdas into Anonymous Classes instead of Java 8's fancy `invokedynamic` / `LambdaMetafactory` / `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass` system. This obviously creates a lot of overhead for the temporary classes and their instances, as well as the overhead of the map, flatMap and filter operations, which usually copy their underlying collections. Is there any particular reason to use the functional approach to a problem when the generally faster iterative approach is available, at least on the bytecode level?

For example, why does

```
for {
  sl <- l
  el <- sl
  if el > 0
} println el.toString.length
```

translate to

```
l.flatMap(sl => sl.filter(el => el > 0).foreach(el => println el.toString.length))
```

Instead of

```
for (sl <- l) // Iterable for loop
{
    for (el <- sl) // Iterable for loop
    {
        println el.toString.length
    }
}
```

Comment: `filter` there is generally `withFilter` - the compiler will generate a warning when it has to fall back to filter, and I believe 2.11 or 2.12 outright rejects `if` guards on classes not implementing `withFilter`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4211103/3004881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implemented that way because that's how the SLS defines it. The rules are rather large to paste here, but they're fully included in the spec.

[For Comprehensions and For Loops](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops)

> **Example**
>   The following code produces all pairs of numbers between 1 and
>   n−1 whose sums are prime.
>
> ```
> for  { i <- 1 until n
>        j <- 1 until i
>        if isPrime(i+j)
> } yield (i, j)
> ```
>
> The for comprehension is translated to:
>
> ```
> (1 until n)
>   .flatMap {
>      case i => (1 until i)
>        .withFilter { j => isPrime(i+j) }
>        .map { case j => (i, j) } }
> ```

Comment: I see. But apart from the spec, is there a scenario where the simple `for` loop could *not* be translated to the iterative version? (Since `yield` returns a collection, it doesn't work with it anyway)

Comment: @Clashsoft you'd have to look into 1) how scalac optimizes the AST into jvm bytecode, and then 2) how the jvm optimizes that bytecode.

Comment: The reason why the Scala compiler doesn't optimize this particular special case is that the Scala compiler developers do not like special cases. So, this special case is nothing special, in a manner of speaking, *no* special cases are optimized by the compiler. The compiler developers prefer to implement powerful general optimizations that benefit a lot of code, rather than littering the compiler with micro-optimizations that only benefit specific corner cases. Making first-class functions faster, for example, would be beneficial in a much wider set of circumstances.

Comment: And, in fact, as of [Scala 2.12](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M1#new_features_in_the_212_series), the minimum Java platform version for running Scala programs will be bumped to Java 8, precisely because first-class functions will get treated similar to how Java 8 does it: "The following changes are planned for Scala 2.12:

Java 8 style closures. The Scala compiler will emit closure classes (lambdas) in the same manner as Java 8." Also relevant: "New backend and optimizer. […] Scala 2.12 will also ship with a new inliner and bytecode optimizer."