# Why is a filter implementation needed in this case?

Tags: scala, filter, foreach, pattern-matching

The following code fails to compile:

```
scala> case class T3( x:Int,y:Int,z:Int) { def foreach[U](f:((Int,Int,Int)) => U) = f( (x,y,z) ) }
defined class T3

scala> for ( (x,y,z) <- T3(1,2,3) ) { println (x,y,z) }
<console>:10: error: value filter is not a member of T3
              for ( (x,y,z) <- T3(1,2,3) ) { println (x,y,z) }
                                 ^
```

I don't see why filter is needed for this piece of code since it will always match?

**EDIT**
For my problem, it is enough to add a nonsense implementation of filter like so:

```
scala> case class T3( x:Int,y:Int,z:Int) { def foreach[U](f:((Int,Int,Int)) => U) = f( (x,y,z) )
     | def filter(p: ((Int,Int,Int)) => Boolean) = this }
defined class T3

scala> for ( (x,y,z) <- T3(1,2,3) ) { println (x,y,z) }
(1,2,3)

scala>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), a generator `p <- e` is translated to a `withFilter` call unless the pattern is 'irrefutable'. Three conditions are given for a pattern to be irrefutable:

1. `p` is a variable pattern.

Clearly, this isn't the case.

1. `p` is a typed pattern `x : T'` and `'T <: T'`, where `e : T`.

Again, this clearly isn't the case.

1. `p` is a constructor pattern `c(p1,...,pn)`, the type `T` is an instance of class `c`, the primary constructor (§5.3) of type `T` has argument types `T1, ..., Tn`, and each `pi` is irrefutable for `Ti`.

<strike>The problem here is that whilst `(x,y,z)` is a constructor pattern for `Tuple3`, the type `T` (here `T3`) is not an instance of `Tuple3` - only the return type of the `foreach` method is. Conversion of non irrefutable patterns takes place as the first step in desugaring `for` expressions, so before the return type to `foreach` is considered.</strike>

As such, the pattern can't be shown to be irrefutable.

Edit: Whilst the above seems to make sense in light of the spec, I can't see how it *actually* makes any sense! For example, my explanation would suggest that the following pattern should be irrefutable:

```
(a,b) <- (1,2)
```

Despite the fact that it makes no sense! It's clearly looking at something to determine the result type to check irrefutability against, and it seems like that something is the `withFilter` method. Which would suggest that it needs a `withFilter` method in order to determine whether the `withFilter` method is needed...

There seem to be a variety of bugs surrounding this: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1893 for example. I'd guess that perhaps this is another broken case.

Comment: I'm confused when you say `(a,b) <- (1,2)` shouldn't be irrefutable... can you elaborate more, please?

Comment: `(a,b) = (1,2)` should be fine, but clearly it's not the type of `e` in `p <- e` that `p` should be checked for irrefutability against - it's the type of element 'inside' the container.

Comment: doesn't `p` = `(a,b)` conform to the third case of irrefutability in the *SLS*? `(a,b)` is equivalent to `Tuple2(a,b)` and `Tuple2` is a case class so we have the extracted constructor type `T` corresponding to `Tuple2`. Then the arguments' pattern `a` and `b` should be irrefutable since they're variable patterns. Am I wrong?

Comment: The point is that the SLS states that for a pattern `p <-e`, `p` should be checked for irrefutability against the type of `e` - but the type of `e` is the container type, rather than the contained type. I couldn't find in the SLS where it specifies which type `e` the pattern is actually checked for irrefutability against, but experimentation suggests it's derived from `withFilter`'s type.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, I's missing that the SLS says "not irrefutable for the type of *e*". I agree that it doesn't makes much sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
 for ( T3(x,y,z) <- List(T3(1,2,3)) ) { println (x,y,z) }
```

also this:

```
 for ( T3(x,y,z) <- Some(T3(1,2,3)) ) { println (x,y,z) }
```

It seems the `for` comprehension expects boxed values.

Comment: The thing is that the tuple in the initial example *is* boxed, by `T3`.

Comment: I expected `for ( T3(x,y,z) <- T3(1,2,3) ) { println (x,y,z) }` to work too but didn't. `for((x,y,z) <- Tuple3(1,2,3))yield x` fails also. I'll try read up more and get back to you.