# Either for-comprehension different behavior in 2.9 and 2.10

Tags: scala

Scala 2.10 seems have updated the for comprehension for Either.
In 2.10:

```
scala> val a = Right(5)
a: scala.util.Right[Nothing,Int] = Right(5)

scala> for {aa: Int <- a.right} yield {aa}
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: scala.util.Either[Nothing,Int] => ?
          for {aa: Int <- a.right} yield {aa}
                       ^
```

In 2.9.3, the above is okay.

```
scala> val a = Right(5)
a: Right[Nothing,Int] = Right(5)

scala> for {aa: Int <- a.right} yield {aa}
res0: Product with Serializable with Either[Nothing,Int] = Right(5)
```

It is very easy to fix by just removing the type for aa in 2.10. But I am wondering why the behavior changes as such between 2.9 and 2.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be due to this [open bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1336) which adds `withFilter` even if its not required. To explain it, some brief intro:

In `2.10` compiling below with `-Xprint:typer` gives

```
for {aa <- a.right} yield {aa}

Temp.this.a.right.map[Int](((aa: Int) => aa))

 //for below
for {aa:Int <- a.right} yield {aa}

a.right.filter[Nothing](((check$ifrefutable$1: Int) => (check$ifrefutable$1: Int @unchecked) match {
  case (aa @ (_: Int)) => true
  case _ => false
})).map[B](((aa: Int) => aa))
```

This is obviously an error in second case. Because in short you are [doing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either$$RightProjection@filter[X](p:B=%3EBoolean):Option[scala.util.Either[X,B]]) `Option[scala.util.Either[Nothing,Int]].map((aa:Int) => aa)` which is an error as it expects a map over `Either` rather than `Int`.

In **Scala 2.9.3**, for both the above cases it gives:

```
a.right.map[Int](((aa: Int) => aa))
```

---

In `2.10` a `with-filter` clause is added. From [for-comprehension specs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops):

> The translation scheme is as follows. In a first step, every generator
>   p <- e, where p is **not irrefutable** for the type of e is replaced by
>
> p <- e.withFilter { case p => true; case _ => false }

In your first case, `p` is [Irrefutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns) (Point-1 in spec) so withFilter is not added. In your second case, `p` is [Irrefutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns) (Point-2  so `withFilter` should not be added. But it does which is a bug.

Similar read: [why does filter have to be defined for pattern matching in a for loop in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala)

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you! I didn't know -Xprint:typer before. It is a very neat tool.