# Scala for-comprehension with tuple decomposition

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

```
for {
  a <- Some(1)
  b <- Some(2)
} yield (a, b)
```

returns `Some((1, 2))`

```
for {
  a <- Right(1).right
  b <- Left(2).left
} yield (a, b)
```

returns `Left((1, 2))`

---

Now I want to decompose tuples in the for comprehension.

```
for {
  (a, b) <- Some((1, 2))
  (c, d) <- Some((3, 4))
} yield (a, b, c, d)
```

returns `Some((1, 2, 3, 4))`

```
for {
  (a, b) <- Right((1, 2)).right
  (c, d) <- Left((3, 4)).left
} yield (a, b, c, d)
```

fails to compile:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required: scala.util.Either[Nothing,(Int, Int)]
                   (a, b) <- Right((1, 2)).right

error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required: scala.util.Either[(Int, Int),Nothing]
```

---

Why doesn't this last example work? What is the difference?

Comment: There is a [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5589) reported for this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug:

[SI-5589: For-comprehension on Either.RightProjection with Tuple2 extractor in generator fails to compile](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5589)

`withFilter()` is called (some documentation references `filter()`, but that was changed in 2.8), which messes with the type inference.

`withFilter()` is used for things like `for(a <- b if c)`, though according to the [6.19](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) it shouldn't be used in this case.

This latter bug is captured in [SI-1336: spec requires type checking of for-comprehension to consider refutability](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1336), which has been open for seven years (2008).

Perhaps some future generation will find the fix.

---

See [why does filter have to be defined for pattern matching in a for loop in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala?lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Because the generators for (Any, Any) <- Either are not "irrefutable" filters are added into the desugared code ([why does filter have to be defined for pattern matching in a for loop in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala)), resulting in:

```
Right((1, 2)).right.filter { case (a, b) => true; case _ => false }.flatMap({
  case(a, b) => Left((3, 4)).left.filter { case (c, d) => true; case _ => false }.map({case (c, d) =>
    (a, b, c, d)
  })
})
```

The filters are where the compilation error occurs because the filter method for Right looks like this (the Left one is similar):

```
def filter[X](p: B => Boolean): Option[Either[X, B]] = e match {
  case Left(_) => None
  case Right(b) => if(p(b)) Some(Right(b)) else None
}
```

Which means that the compiler is trying to do the following:

```
(T1, T2) match {
  case Left(_) => None
  case Right(b) => if(p(b)) Some(Right(b)) else None
}
```

Which fails since (T1, T2) cannot be cast into Either[A, B] (what Right extends) where A is Nothing and B is (Int, Int).

You can get something close to this by using:

```
for {
  a <- Right((1, 2)).right
  b <- Left((3, 4)).left
} yield (a, b) match {
  case ((c, d), (e, f)) => (c, d, e, f)
  case _ => 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be a limitation of for expressions. Translating

```
for {
  (a, b) <- Some((1, 2))
  (c, d) <- Some((3, 4))
} yield (a, b, c, d)
```

into

```
Some((1, 2)).flatMap({case(a, b) =>
  Some((3, 4)).map({case (c, d) =>
    (a, b, c, d)
  })
})
```

works both ways. With the `Either` expression, only the map/flatMap
version works.

```
for {
  (a, b) <- Right((1, 2)).right
  (c, d) <- Left((3, 4)).left
} yield (a, b, c, d)


Right((1, 2)).right.flatMap({
  case(a, b) => Left((3, 4)).left.map({case (c, d) =>
    (a, b, c, d)
  })
})
```

I don't recommend using `Either`, instead use the `\/` type from
scalaz. http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Either.html `Either` isn't
left nor right-leaning, which is a problem because it doesn't specify
where the error or the value goes.

Comment: `Either` might not be right or left leaning, but `LeftProjection` and `RightProjection` certainly are!

Comment: @PaulDraper yes, but then you'll have to specify `.right` or `.left` every time you want to use it. And I prefer my code without noise.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

```
//getting tuple

def parseFrame(bb: ByteBuffer) = {
   val sbb = bb.slice();
   val len = Frames.getLengthField(sbb)
   val frameType = sbb.get()
   val flags = sbb.get()
   val streamId = Frames.getStreamId(sbb)
   (len, frameType, flags, streamId)
}

//matching tuple in for compressions
 
def do_someting(bb: ByteBuffer) = {
  for {
    t <- IO(parseFrame(bb))
    len = t._1
    frameType = t._2
    flags = t._3
    streamId = t._4
  } yield (len)
}
```