# Why does a for-comprehension used with an extractor of type tuple result in a compile warning on `filter`?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, extractor

Given the following code snippelt:

```
import scala.util.Try

def foo(x:Int) : (Int, String) = {
  (x+1, x.toString)
}

def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val r1: Try[(Int, String)] = for {
    v <- Try { foo(3) }
  } yield v

  val r2: Try[(Int, String)] = for {
    (i, s)  <- Try { foo(3) } // compile warning refers to this line
  } yield (i, s)
}
```

**1. Why does a compile of the above code throw the following warning?**

```
`withFilter' method does not yet exist on scala.util.Try[(Int, String)], using `filter' method instead
[warn]       (i, s)  <- Try { foo(3) }
[warn]                      ^
[warn] one warning found
```

**2. Why is `withFilter` used at all when extracting to a tuple?**

### Update

- The warning occurs with Scala 2.10.5
- The warning does **not** occur with Scala 2.11.7

Independent of the warning message, I'm heavily interested to know if `withFilter` is used? (see question 2 )

Comment: Which Scala version are you using ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens: Good hint! 2.10.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `Try.withFilter` was only added in 2.11 (see [`Try` 2.10.6](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.6/#scala.util.Try) and [`Try` 2.11.0](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/#scala.util.Try))

`withFilter` is used instead of `filter` in a for comprehension because it is lazy, you can read a more comprehensive comparison in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617378/withfilter-instead-of-filter).

Your second for comprehension is similar to :

```
Try(foo(3)).withFilter {
  case (i, s) => true
  case _      => false
} map(identity)
```

Because in Scala 2.10.5 `Try.withFilter` doesn't exists, it falls back to using `filter` (which creates a new `Try`).

---

**Edit**: Why you need the `withFilter` is not that obvious in your case, because you aren't actually filtering with the `(i, s)` pattern match.

If you wrote the for comprehension below, it is more clear that you (can) filter when you add a pattern match in the left hand side of a for comprehension.

```
for {
  (i, "3") <- Try(foo(3))
} yield i
```

Which is analogous to :

```
Try(foo(3)) withFilter {
  case (i, "3") => true
  case _        => false
} map { case (i, "3") => i }
```

As you can see `withFilter` is not only used when you add an if guard, but also when you pattern match.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on **why** the withFilter is used? Why is it necessary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala