# How to annotate types of expressions within a Scala for expression

Tags: scala, filter, pattern-matching, monads, type-inference

I'm wondering how to (safely) add type ascriptions to the lefthand side of Scala for expressions.

When working with complex for expressions, the inferred types are often hard to follow, or can go off track, and it's desirable to annotate the expressions within the `for {..}` block, to check that you and the compiler agree. An illustrative code sketch that uses the [Eff monad](https://github.com/atnos-org/eff-cats):

```
for {
  e1: Option[(Int, Vector[Int])] <- complexCalc
  e2 <- process(e1)
} yield e2

def complexCalc[E]: Eff[E, Option[(Int, Vector[Int])]] = ???
```

However, this conflicts with Scala's support for pattern matching on the LHS of a for-expression.

- As discussed in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380831/why-does-filter-have-to-be-defined-for-pattern-matching-in-a-for-loop-in-scala), Scala treats the type ascription `: Option[(Int, Vector[Int])]` as a pattern to be matched.
- The compiler has the concept of *irrefutable* patterns, which always match. Conversely, a *refutable* pattern might not match, and so when used in for expression, the [righthand-side expression must provide a `withFilter` method to handle the non-matching case](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops).
- Due to a [longstanding compiler bug/limitation](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1336), tuples and other common [constructor patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns) seem never to be treated as irrefutable.

The net result is that adding a type ascription makes the LHS pattern seem refutable and requires a `filter` op to be defined on the RHS. A symptom is compiler errors like `value filter is not a member of org.atnos.eff.Eff[E,Option[(Int, Vector[Int])]]`.

If there any syntactic form that can be used to ascribe types to the intermediate expressions containing tuples, within for expressions, without encountering refutable pattern matching?

Comment: Could you give an example (complexCalc and process) that demonstrate this? The previous question you link to doesn't discuss type annotation in that position. Are you passing in `Any`s?

Comment: Couldn't you ascribe the right hand side ? Something like `for { e <- (complexCalc : Eff[E, Option[(Int, Vector[Int])]]) ; ... } yield e2` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens Yes that works. The RHS types are more complex because they include the monadic wrapper (eg above `Eff[E, <lhs>]`), so was hoping to find a way to annotate the simpler  LHS "payload" type

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's extensive discussion of this problem, and the current best solution, in this [Scalaz PR](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/728#issuecomment-45777181) *.

The work around is to add the type ascription in an assignment on the line below:

```
for {
  e <- complexCalc
  e1: Option[(Int, Vector[Int])] = e
  e2 <- process(e1)
} yield e2

def complexCalc[E]: Eff[E, Option[(Int, Vector[Int])]] = ???
```