# Mock for comprehension in scala

Tags: scala, mocking, for-comprehension

I have this piece of code

```
   for (element <- table.find;
     Right(info) = exceptionManager(mapper.getInfoFromDbObject(element)))
yield info
```

and I would like to unit test it. I want to mock table.find in order to return a sequence of element that I want. I have tried mocking `hasNext()` and `next()` methods of Iterator interface but it seems it is not working. Which is the method to mock a for comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each for comprehension is translated to `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` method calls. So you should mock at least them.

You can find more information here (for example):

http://www.lambdascale.com/2010/12/the-adventures-of-a-java-developer-in-monadland/

And of course you will find deep explanation in [Programming in Scala book](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed).

#### Edit

But as **Dave Griffith** said, you can just initialize new `Iterator` yourself. Here is an example that uses [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/):

```
val table = mock[TableClass]
when(table find) thenReturn Iterator(new ModelObject(1), new ModelObject(2))
```

#### Edit 1

As **Daniel** noticed, `filter` method is now deprecated in for comprehensions. Instead you should use `withFilter`. For more information you can look in this thread:

http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Rethinking-filter-td2009215.html#a2009218

and this related SO question:

[guide to move from filter to withFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188316/guide-to-move-from-filter-to-withfilter)

Comment: It is not feasible. Table is injected and it is a MongoCollection. So I can mock a MongoCollection. Find method returns a trait MongoCursorBase that extends Iterator so returning an Iterator is not possible. Right?

Comment: @Matroska: It seems to be more complicated. You should mock whole MongoCursorBase. But I wonder why you want to mock so low level API. If you have DAO layer, then you can make integration tests for it (not-unit-tests, that involve DB interaction). Then in order to test you service (business-logic) layer you just mock your DAOs. If you keep your DAOs single-purposed, then there is nothing to test except DB queries.

Comment: This is the dao. Yes probably it would be better to make integration tests. Since I wanted to test the Either way to manage exception I was thinking using unit test. I think to have solved creating an hand made Mock object that extends MongoCursorBase and delegates map, filter, flatmap, next and has next to a real Iterator implementation.

Comment: The days of `filter` are somewhat behind. These days, `withFilter` it is.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should mock the "map" method, but you're probably better off simply having table.find return one of the predefined collection types.

Comment: table.find returns a MongoCursorBase that implements Iterator. How can I proceed? Thanks

Comment: @Matroska: suppose your table has type `TableClass`. You can mock find method like this: `val table = mock[TableClass]; when(table.find) thenReturn Iterator(new ModelObject(1), new ModelObject(2));` with [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/)