# Iterating over a Scala wrapped list

Tags: list, scala, iterator, wrapper, scala-collections

I need to encapsulate a list in a separate Object in Scala acting as a wrapper class for my collection. I need this to implement some methods to act with the list (in detail I need to find objects in the List which are associated with other object in the list).

So first of all my code:

```
object Axons {
    var axonList=List[Axon]();
    var pos=0;
    def init(al: List[Axon]) {
        axonList= al;
    }
    def reverse(): List[Axon]  = axonList.reverse
    def get(count: Int) = axonList(count)
    def getList(): List[Axon] = axonList
    def length(): Int = axonList.length

}
```

Now iterating happens like:

```
for (axon <- axons.getList)
```

This looks kinda ugly to me, but I could not figure out how to implement an Iterator which is usable multiple times to iterate over the collection.

Another approach, just using the plain list, is to define a function which uses fold to shrink the list just holding the objects I want to have.

What you think is a more common way?
Filter to a seperate list just holding needed objects or using an iterator.
In my opinion it would be cleaner to encapsulate my Axons collection in a seperate object, from a software desing point of view.

What you think fits best for the problem?

(If you ask yourself what I'm doing and what an axon is; its a part of a neural network http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network and the Axons collection wraps the connections between a source and a destination neuron)

thanks and kind regards

=================================================

Solution from Felix

```
object Axons extends Traversable[Axon] {
    var axonList=List[Axon]();
    def init(al: List[Axon]) {
        axonList= al;
    }
    def reverse(): List[Axon]  = axonList.reverse
    def get(count: Int) = axonList(count)

        //look here!
    def foreach[U](f: Axon=> U): Unit = axonList.foreach(f)
    //end ... 
    def length(): Int = axonList.length
    def findAxonsBySource(sourceNeuron: Neuron): List[Axon] = {
        axonList collect { 
            case axon: Axon if axon.getSourceNeuron == sourceNeuron  => axon 
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this:

```
for (axon <- axons.getList)
```

compiles. You meant to put Axons in upper case right?

Anyway, you can do something like this:

```
object Test extends Traversable[Int]{
val list = List(1,2,1337,4)
def foreach[U](f: Int=> U): Unit = list.foreach(f)
}
```

and test it like so:

```
Test foreach println
1
2
1337
4
```

I am not totally sure I understood the problem correctly, but I hope it helps :)

**edit**

Just some thoughts on your post. The good thing about Scala is that you can sometimes skip steps that you would be forced to take in Java for example. Don't create classes and big type schemes for everything unless you feel it is really justifiable. My approach is always to fold/map/filter and what not until I get what I need to test out my software. If I need to increase performance/modularity I can start redoing parts of my software. Mostly I get short programs and rarely have to redo stuff.
I see the functional aspect of Scala as a gift to reduce boiler plate code immensely.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to be able to use `Axons` in list comprehensions, then you just need to implement `map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter` methods in it and (in your case) delegate these calls to to `axonList`. When you have made this, you can use `axons` like this:

```
for (axon <- axons)
```

More info you can find in this SO answer:

[Mock for comprehension in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128229/mock-for-comprehension-in-scala/5128262#5128262)

Comment: ah ok, got it. axons was a List[Axon], now I have Axons as a object, so i can use Axons in my code right?

Comment: @evildead: if by 'my code' you mean for comprehensions, then yes - with `map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter` you make class `Axons` usable in for comprehensions. But if you was using some list methods directly (like `foldLeft` of `reduce`) then you need to modify your exiting code and use `axons.axonList.foldLeft`, etc.